# Integrate Taurus test suites on Atlassian Bamboo CI

Tags: jmeter, bamboo, blazemeter, taurus

I am currently facing the following issue. I have a set of test cases that were implemented using the [Taurus framework](http://gettaurus.org/). On my local workstation I manage to successfully execute them by execution the following command on the console:

```
bzt test_script.yml
```

generating the output:

```
11:18:16 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.7.2
11:18:16 INFO: Starting with configs: ['test_script.yml']
11:18:16 INFO: Configuring...
11:18:16 INFO: No personal config: /home/userid/.bzt-rc
11:18:16 INFO: Artifacts dir: /home/userid/taurus_results/test_endpoint
11:18:16 INFO: Preparing...
11:18:20 INFO: Starting...
11:18:20 INFO: Waiting for results...
11:18:20 INFO: Waiting for finish...
```

as well as it start to show the stats:

[image]

However, when I execute the same script by the same command on our Atlassian Bamboo CI server the job gets stuck on the line:

```
11:18:16 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.7.2
```

and the job never finishes.

I would like to understand:

- What is going on?
- Why the job does not go forward?
- Is it possible to shut off the Taurus stats?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I already anwered the third question by this post: http://gettaurus.org/docs/ConsoleReporter/

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone may find it useful I solved the problem by executing the following command:

```
printf '' | bzt test_script.yml
```

The output on our CI server is the following:

[image]